# What's the difference between virtual circuit switching and circuit switching?

Tags: network, switching

Circuit switching's packets take the same route as virtual circuit switching's do.

So, how do I distinguish between virtual circuit switching and circuit switching?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the good old days of cables that consisted of a large number of copper wires, and switching stations with relays that effectively implemented a big crossbar, circuit switching meant that the provider put all the switches in the position that made a real (electrical) circuit from one client to another. The two literally had a cable for their own private use (for as long as then connection was established).

Virtual circuit switching gives the clients the impression that they have a dedicated cable, while in fact they are allocated time-slots (or frequency bands, or some other shared slice) in all the cables that make up the connection. This better matches the current economic reality that a cable is very expensive, but has a bandwidth that far exceeds the needs of most clients, hence sharing is economical.

The difference between a virtual switched circuit and plain packet switching is that for a virtual circuit all the steps that make up the connection are determined when the connection is established, and the buffers and bandwidth at each step is claimed and thus guaranteed. For (plain) packet switching there is no such circuit creation: each packet finds its own way through the network, and has to hope that sufficient buffers and bandwidth is available at each step.

Comment: so the cables of  circuit switching  is exclusive even when the connection is not established. Am I right?

Comment: No, they are exclusive for the duration of the connection. Otherwise there would be no switching.

Comment: Virtual circuit switching do not always take the same route when every connection is established, but circuit switching do. Am I right? : )

Comment: for example, route of virtual circuit is variable, and route of circuit switching is constant.

Comment: No, I don't think that is a necessary consequence of virtual versus non-virtual switching. In both cases the selected route could either be statically predictable, or depend on some dynamic aspect (like the currently connected routes).

Answer (score 0):

Virtual circuit switching is a packet switching mechanism. In that a Virtual path is established between source and destination before the transmission of data. It is data traffic.

Whereas, Circuit switching, happens in three steps,

1. circuit establishment
2. Data transfer
3. Circuit Disconnect

Circuit switching is voice traffic. Generally used in telephone networks.

Comment: Are there another different stuff between them? Because they both have circuit establishment and data transfer. : )